# Greybox Images Not Loading possible URL issue?

Tags: javascript, image, url, greybox

I am trying to use Greybox and I am getting frustrated with it not finding my images that I wish to display. I think it may have to do with relative URLs and not pointing in the right spot. But I am not certain. I feel like I have tried every possible URL combination.

Is this the issue, or am I missing something entirely??
I have read the FAQ on Greybox here: http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/FAQ/ but it didn't really offer me a solution.

I would be very grateful for any assistance. Thanks.

***Note:*** Looks like the server is case sensitive.

URL to the page in question is: http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma.html
Images are located: /refresh/emma/images/
Images are labeled: screen01.jpg, screen02.jpg, screen03.jpg etc.

Here is the greybox content in the header of my HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var GB_ROOT_DIR = "http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/refresh/banner/Scripts/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
```

Here is the image set that I have defined (Now using absolute URLs):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var image_set = [{'caption': 'Screenshot 1', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/images/screen01.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 2', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/images/screen02.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 3', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/images/screen03.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 4', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/images/screen04.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 5', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/images/screen05.jpg'}];
</script>
```

Here is the anchor tag in the HTML:

```
<a href="" class="emmalink" onclick="return GB_showImageSet(image_set, 1)">Screenshots</a>
```

***EDIT:*** ***Here's the code that works for me:***

In between the  and  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var GB_ROOT_DIR = "http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_set = [{'caption': 'Screenshot 1', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen01.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 2', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen02.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 3', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen03.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 4', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen04.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'Screenshot 5', 'url': 'http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen05.jpg'}];
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<a href="" class="emmalink" onclick="return GB_showImageSet(image_set, 1)">Screenshots</a>
```

Comment: It's most likely because of the relative paths, try absolute URLs. I was trying this myself but could not find your actual images - it's also possible the images don't exist. Can you link to one of the images directly as an example - and to be sure they exist where you think they do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I will look into the images right now.

Comment: The images are there on the server. But I cannot access them via my browser. Says its forbidden. I am so confused.

I have also placed the images in question at the following path: Refresh/images/ with still no luck.

Comment: Absolute URLs did not solve this. :(

Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ACMEexp: Well I'm getting a 404 on your page now, so no I don't have any other suggestions. I'd still like to see a direct link to one of your images, I think you're dismissing the idea too quickly. All the images in your edit are giving me 404s.

Comment: @Wesley Murch:
A direct link to the images:
http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/screen01.jpg

Comment: If you're getting a 403, this is a server configuration problem... Can you show an URL that gives you the "forbidden" message?

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks for your response.
http://www.ecometrix.ca/refresh/emma/images/ shows a 403 forbidden

Comment: @ACME that's okay, it just refuses to list the images present in the directory. That shouldn't be a problem as long as the images themselves work

Comment: @Pekka: Glad to hear that. Although I am still at a loss why I cannot get greybox to function properly.

Comment: There is a JavaScript error that is causing Greybox to fail. (See the error console) I have no concrete idea where it comes from though - I think the best thing to do is to double-check whether Greybox is getting initialized properly. Where did you take that code example from? Can you post a link?

Comment: @ACMEexp: Looks like you got it working with the absolute URLs from my end on Firefox 4. Feel free to answer your own question with the details of the solution if you think it will help others. EDIT: I see, it's still a bit funny. If you skip two images forward and then go back - they load, but not the first time. And scrolling the page breaks. Ah well, Good Luck!

Comment: @Pekka: Greybox is found here: [link]http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/[link]
I tried the javascript console, and it reveals that the errors come from the dropdown menu. Sigh.
How would I go about verifying that Greybox is getting initialized properly?

@Wesley: You are right. The images show when you click twice forward, and then back to the beginning. This is so whack.
 **If** I find a solution, I will for sure post the results.

Comment: @ACME oh, indeed! You're right. That's weird: The images indeed get loaded, they just don't get displayed. Does it work if you disable the other stuff?

Comment: @Pekka: Good question. Looking into it now.

Comment: Thanks to both @Wesley Murch, and @Pekka for your time and assistance. It seems to work now and I am very grateful. I am not entirely certain why it works now, and not previously. I will post the code that does provide a positive result above as an edit. Hopefully this will help others who also may be at their wits end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works for me:

In between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var GB_ROOT_DIR = "http://www.yourabsolute.url/including/filepath/to/greybox/";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/filepath/to/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/filepath/to/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/filepath/to/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="/filepath/to/greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image_set = [{'caption': 'This is the image caption displayed.', 'url': 'http://www.yourabsolute.url/including/filepath/to/greybox/your_image01.jpg'},
                 {'caption': 'This is the second image caption displayed.', 'url': 'http://www.yourabsolute.url/including/filepath/to/greybox/your_image02.jpg'}];
</script>
```

After the `<body>` tag:

Click Here to launch Greybox.

**Note:** There seems to be a bug with Greybox v.5.54 in that images don't always load on the first try. It just displays the greybox correctly but with no content. If you close the greybox that you launched the first time, and try click on the link one more time before refreshing the page, greybox will launch correctly. Including all appropriate content.

**Install:** Installing Greybox v5.53 instead of v5.54 seems to have solved the issue of the images not loading on the first try. Hope this helps.